# Clion unistd.h doesn't recognize fork() & getppid()

Tags: fork, clion, unistd.h

When writing this simple code with fork() and getppid() aren't resolved by the IDE

I've Windows 11
My Clion version is 3.15
CMakeLists is CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99

Thanks for your time.
[Attachments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNr8T.png)

Comment: Windows doesn't have `fork`, or really any useful POSIX functionality (POSIX is the standard used by e.g. Linux or macOS). The woefully incomplete POSIX compatibility layer Windows used to have has been more or less obsoleted for a long time.

Comment: ohh makes sense!